# Include absences in attendance

Tags: sql, sql-server

I was able to display the attendance from my SQL but I can't display the weekdays where I was absent.

Here is my table:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ctTE4.png)

Here is my current query

```
Userid  Date        TimeIn   TimeOut    Remark
7       7/25/2023   7:55:14             Didn't Clock Out
7       7/24/2023   7:41:27  17:07:59   
7       7/21/2023   7:47:03  17:17:37   
7       7/20/2023   7:51:43  17:04:53   
7       7/19/2023   7:53:53  17:07:28   
7       7/14/2023   8:47:35  17:17:15   
7       7/13/2023   8:36:06  17:07:25   
7       7/12/2023   7:49:26  17:05:15   
7       7/7/2023    7:50:55  17:03:52   
7       7/6/2023    7:52:57  17:11:54
```

But I want to display like this:

```
Userid  Date        TimeIn    TimeOut    Remark
7       7/25/2023   7:55:14              Didn't Clock Out
7       7/24/2023   7:41:27   17:07:59  
7       7/21/2023   7:47:03   17:17:37  
7       7/20/2023   7:51:43   17:04:53  
7       7/19/2023   7:53:53   17:07:28  
7       7/18/2023                        absent
7       7/17/2023                        absent
7       7/14/2023   8:47:35   17:17:15  
7       7/13/2023   8:36:06   17:07:25  
7       7/12/2023   7:49:26   17:05:15  
7       7/7/2023    7:50:55   17:03:52  
7       7/6/2023    7:52:57   17:11:54
```

Here is my code, I hope somebody will update the correct query.

```
SELECT UserID 'Userid', 
    CONVERT(DATE,TransactionTime) 'Date',
    MIN(CAST(CONVERT(TIME,TransactionTime) AS VARCHAR(8))) 'TimeIN',
    CASE WHEN MIN(CAST(CONVERT(TIME,TransactionTime) AS VARCHAR(8))) = MAX(CAST(CONVERT(TIME,TransactionTime) AS VARCHAR(8))) THEN 
        '' 
    ELSE
        MAX(CAST(CONVERT(TIME,TransactionTime) AS VARCHAR(8)))
    END 'TimeOut',
    CASE WHEN MIN(CAST(CONVERT(TIME,TransactionTime) AS VARCHAR(8))) = MAX(CAST(CONVERT(TIME,TransactionTime) AS VARCHAR(8))) THEN 
        'Didn''t Clock Out' 
    ELSE
        ''
    END 'Remark'
FROM NGAC_AUTHLOG WHERE UserID='0007'
GROUP BY UserID,DATEPART(MONTH,TransactionTime),CONVERT(DATE,TransactionTime)
Order by CONVERT(DATE,TransactionTime) desc
```

First Result from comments: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6DgHY.png)

Last Results from comments:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BL4Ca.png)

Comment: Please also include sample data from the base table `NGAC_AUTHLOG`

Comment: table 1 is the sample data from NGAC_AUTHLOG

Comment: Your question still does not make clear what is 1) data in the table 2) expected result 3) actual result. I do not see how "*table 1 is the sample data from NGAC_AUTHLOG*", it looks more that you are showing 2 and 3. Please [edit]. We want to see those three terms/headers with their data in the question.

Comment: And how does one know what controls "absent" rows? You didn't include any logic on it.  Is it some sort of mon-friday thing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way to solve this is to add a calendar table to your database, where in that table you'll have a column for the date, and (at least) a column that indicates if that date is a workday or not.
[Here's an article](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4054/creating-a-date-dimension-or-calendar-table-in-sql-server/) by Aaron Bertrand explaining how you can easily build one. His calendar table is very informative in terms of what is stored in it, but for the purpose if this question a simple bit column called `IsWorkDay` will suffice.
Something as simple as that would do the trick:

```
Date        IsWorkDay
2023-07-01  0          -- Saturday
2023-07-02  0          -- Sunday
2023-07-03  1
2023-07-04  1
2023-07-05  1
2023-07-06  1
2023-07-07  1
2023-07-08  0
2023-07-09  0
2023-07-10  1
```

I've created a sample script for generating a years worth of dates for such a table, including the week day name - you can use it if you want or create your own. Note that my script doesn't take into account holydays, only weekends (Saturday and Sunday). You can run it on [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/pmaydXSh) and change to your needs.

Once you have your dates table set up, it's a simple `LEFT JOIN` query:

```
DECLARE @UserId int = 7

SELECT @UserId As UserId, 
       C.Date, 
       N.TimeIn, 
       N.TimeOut, 
       CASE WHEN N.Date IS NULL AND C.IsWorkDay = 1 THEN 
           'absent'
       ELSE 
           N.Remark
       END As Remark
FROM Calendar As C
LEFT JOIN NGAC_AUTHLOG As N
    ON C.Date = N.Date
    AND N.UserId = @UserId
```

Note: You'll need to select `@UserId` and not `N.UserId` because when the user is absent, there will be no record of them in the `NGAC_AUTHLOG` table.
That is also why the condition `N.UserId = @UserId` is in the `ON` clause and not in the `WHERE` clause - because if it was in the `WHERE` clause, that would effectively convert your left join to an inner join.

### **Update**

@siggemannen commented, rightfully, "You probably want to add some selection on non-weekend dates."

There are two ways to do that - you can either choose to select only work days - so adding a `WHERE` clause to the query (and removing the now-redundant second condition in the `CASE` expression) -

```
...CASE WHEN N.Date IS NULL THEN
...
WHERE C.IsWorkDay = 1
```

Or, you can change the `CASE` expression to add a remark for days that aren't work dayes:

```
...CASE WHEN C.IsWorkDay = 0 THEN 
       'Weekend/Holyday'
   WHEN N.Date IS NULL THEN 
       'absent'
   ELSE 
       N.Remark 
   END As Remark
```

Comment: You probably want to add some selection on non-weekend dates.

Comment: @siggemannen Correct. I've updated my answer.

Comment: I read the article but It seems I don't see what calendar should be created.

Comment: my output is : 0 NULL NULL NULL  absent

Comment: My mistake, sorry. Date should be taken from the calendar table. fiexd. but I don't know why you get `0` - you should be getting the user id directly from the variable

Comment: Can you show me the sample table from the calendar? also I have put the table in the link above.

Comment: In addition, I have no Timein and Timeout column, it's just a variable, please refer to my table: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ctTE4.png

Comment: I've updated my answer with some more information on the calendar table. regarding your last comment - you can still calculate the timein and timeout as you did, or simply join the calendar table to the results of your current query

Comment: Thank you, I will work on it , I will update here once done. Thanks man.

Comment: Here is the results: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6DgHY.png i try your code, but it display all the records in my table with the same id, so i try this.

Comment: Your join is wrong... You're left-joining the calendar table to your query, it should be the other way around. If you could post a create and insert script to your table on db fiddle or something like that, it would make it much easier for me to help you.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I think I figure it out to myself.

Comment: 07-17-2023 and 07-18-2023 are not showing: https://i.stack.imgur.com/BL4Ca.png

Comment: I did it, thanks a lot man: https://imgur.com/MVhLun8

Comment: You forgot to include N.date in your select statement :)

Comment: but my problem now is, I can't apply to php hahah, before, my attendance is showing.

Comment: How to DECLARE @UserId int = 7 in php? because it's not working inside sql select statement

Comment: It's working now, I just create a table and insert my userid there from session, and I join that table to my 2tables. Thanks a lot Guys, now I'm at ease  :)